# Performance tuning in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-performance

I've written the following pl/sql code which is updating user_five column based on certain conditions by joining two tables table_1 and table_2. This update happens for all the records in table_1 where col1 is joined. But it is taking too much time. How to tune this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
DECLARE
ISIN_CHECK         VARCHAR2(25) := '&3';
cursor c1 is SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 FROM table_1
WHERE col1 IN (SELECT col1 FROM table_2 WHERE col_n='&2');
rec_count1 number := 1;
 rec_count2 number := 1;
 rec_count3 number := 1;

 BEGIN
--dbms_output.put_line('start');
--dbms_output.put_line('Parm - 3' || ISIN_CHECK);
if (ISIN_CHECK ='ISIN_EGHT') then
--dbms_output.put_line(' entered into isin user_eighy');
for i in c1
loop
    UPDATE table_1 b
    SET  b.USER_FIVE=i.col2
    WHERE  b.col1 in(SELECT col1 FROM table_2 WHERE col_n='&2')
    AND b.col1=i.col1
    AND b.col5=i.col5
    AND b.cs_flag='C';
  rec_count1 := rec_count1 + 1;
  if mod(rec_count1,10) = 0 then
  commit;
--dbms_output.put_line(b.user_five);
  end if;
  end loop;
 ELSIF (ISIN_CHECK ='ISIN_ELVN') then
for i in c1
loop
   UPDATE table_1 b
    SET  b.USER_FIVE=i.col3
    WHERE  b.col1 in(SELECT col1 FROM table_2 WHERE col_n='&2')
    AND b.col1=i.col1
    AND b.col5=i.col5
    AND b.cs_flag='C';
   rec_count2 := rec_count2 + 1;
if mod(rec_count2,10) = 0 then
  commit;
--dbms_output.put_line(b.user_five);
  end if;
  end loop;
ELSE
for i in c1
 loop
      UPDATE table_1 b
    SET  b.USER_FIVE=i.col4
    WHERE  b.col1 in(SELECT col1 FROM table_2 WHERE col_n='&2')
    AND b.col1=i.col1
    AND b.col5=i.col5
    AND b.cs_flag='C';
  rec_count3 := rec_count3 + 1;
if mod(rec_count3,10000) = 0 then
  commit;
--dbms_output.put_line(b.user_five);
   end if;
   end loop;
  END IF;
   COMMIT;

 END;
 /
```

Comment: Throw out cursors and do straight SQL update.

Comment: Not that it is related to the performance issue but you never want to commit within a loop. A quick google or a read of Tom Kytes books will explain why this is such a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a hard time figuring out what you are actually trying to do. I think the first loop comes down to the following update statement:

```
update table_1 b
   set b.user_five = b.col2
 where b.col1 in (select col1
                    from table_2
                   where col_n = '&2')
   and b.cs_flag = 'C';
```

But you use such an elaborate construction that it's hard to tell. Maybe you can explain what it is you are trying to update.

So try to use a simple update statement wherever possible.
If you do need a plsql for loop don't put commit inside the loop. That's totally unnecessary.

Comment: Hi Rene you are right. I'm updating user_five with col2 based on col_n which is basically a list which i'm calling from the unix script.For each col_n i'm updating user_five=col2.

Comment: Now the problem is i'm calling col_n each time from the unix and storing it in a cursor and doing my update. So i feel the logic i'm using is making my code slow.Because in this case for each col_n there are more than 2 million records which has to be updated with user_five=col2. So i was thinking if there was a better logic that i could use.

Comment: Look into external tables. That way you may be able to directly access the list as if it were a table.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/et_concepts.htm#SUTIL011

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is to replace three FOR loops nested in big `IF THEN ELSE`  with only one, whithout any IF statement:

```
for i in c1
loop
    UPDATE table_1 b
    SET  b.USER_FIVE= CASE ISIN_CHECK
                        WHEN 'ISIN_EGHT' THEN i.col2
                        WHEN 'ISIN_ELVN' THEN i.col3
                        ELSE i.col4 
                      END
    WHERE  b.col1 in(SELECT col1 FROM table_2 WHERE col_n='&2')
    AND b.col1=i.col1
    AND b.col5=i.col5
    AND b.cs_flag='C';
```

---

However this code can be simplified more .... there is no any join of two tables, the cursor selects rows from table_1, the update updates table_1 too, and I would use just one update:

```
UPDATE table_1 b
SET  b.USER_FIVE= CASE ISIN_CHECK
                    WHEN 'ISIN_EGHT' THEN b.col2
                    WHEN 'ISIN_ELVN' THEN b.col3
                    ELSE b.col4 
                  END
WHERE  b.col1 in(SELECT col1 FROM table_2 WHERE col_n='&2')
AND b.cs_flag='C';
```

I guess that this can speed up the procedure by 50 ~100 times.
I am assumming here, that rows in table_1 are unique identified by col1, otherwise the latter update is not equivalent to your procedure, because in this case **this procedure is not deterministic**. Look at simple case, say there are following rows in table_1, and ISIN_CHECK = 'ISIN_EGHT' (so we are taking values from col3 to put them into USER_FIVE):

```
+---------------------+
| col1 col3 col4 col5 |
+---------------------+
| 1     1    1    1   |
| 1     2    2    1   |
| 1     3    3    1   |
+---------------------+
```

The cursor is retreving rows in some order - but since there is no ORDER BY clause in the cursor's SQL query, **Oracle does not guarantee any order**. It can return 1 2 3, or 3 2 1 or 2 3 1 - randomly. The procedure updates table_1 for each iteration (updates USER_FIVE of all matching rows in the table), and the final results for the above case can be different depending on the order of rows returned by the cursor --> USER_FIVE of all matching rows will be updated to a value retrieved by the cursor from last row, in this case it could be 1, 2 or 3, but nobody knows which one.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer i'll take into account the first appraoch that you've suggested. You're right col1 in distinct in this case,Since the data i'm handling here is very huge what is the best approack that you would suggest. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

to speed up the query you can make this changes

`cursor c1 is SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 FROM table_1` replace with 
`cursor c1 is SELECT rowid r, col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 FROM table_1`

change conditions in sql cursors 
this must be changed
`'UPDATE table_1 b
    SET  b.USER_FIVE=i.col2
    WHERE  b.col1 in(SELECT col1 FROM table_2 WHERE col_n='&2')
    AND b.col1=i.col1
    AND b.col5=i.col5
    AND b.cs_flag='C';`

with this

`UPDATE table_1 b
    SET  b.USER_FIVE=i.col2
    WHERE  b.col1 in(SELECT col1 FROM table_2 WHERE col_n='&2')
    AND b.rowid = i.r
    AND b.cs_flag='C';`

and this has to be done for all your update statements